# How to start jsconsole.com?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I want to use jsconsole, I open website, write ':listen' in the console and nothing happens. I was not able to find instruction. How should I use it to debug my application in Lumia phone?

Comment: `:help` is very explicit in saying that the usage is `:listen [id]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news, remote debugging has been depreciated as shown here: https://github.com/remy/jsconsole/issues/101

Edit: If you are working with node there is nodejs --inspect https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/ if that is help, there is also is an emulation tool in IE11 for debugging websites on window phone if you are on window 8.1+ https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn255001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Awesome, hope they keep it up for you!